# java pattern matching insenitive to spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) (\\d+) (1$)");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(line);
```

with matches for:

```
1 2 1
```

but not for:

```
1     2     1
```

How can I achieve, that pattern matching is insenitive according to spaces between numbers?

Comment: Use `\s+` for multiple spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\s` for one space and add a `+` that means one ore more spaces.

```
"(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(1$)"
```

If you want zero or more spaces you have to use a `*` instead of the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `quantifier (+)` with a space, to match `one or more` space: -

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(1$)");
```

Similarly there are other `quantifiers`: -

- `*` to match `0 or more`
- `?` to match `0 or 1`